# Build and Run Docker image as non-root user

Tags: java, docker, maven

I have created a docker file and running it as a root user -
Following is my docker file. The below works fine and I can run the image as well.

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean dependency:go-offline
RUN chmod +x run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

I want to run it as non-root user.
The run.sh is as follows

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

I tried to change the dockerfile to

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean dependency:go-offline
RUN groupadd -r -g 2000 mygrp && useradd -u 2000 -r -g mygrp myuser
RUN chown -R myuser:mygrp .

RUN chmod -R 700 run.sh

USER myuser

RUN chmod u+x run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

The images builds fine but when I try to run -
this is the error

```
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at /home/myuser/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to update the `groupadd` instruction.

**Replace:**

`RUN groupadd -r -g 2000 mygrp && useradd -u 2000 -r -g mygrp myuser`

**With this in the Dockerfile:**

`RUN groupadd -r -g 2000 mygrp && useradd -m -d /home/myuser/ -s /bin/bash -u 2000 -r -g mygrp myuser`

**TL;DR**

From the error message, it is quite clear that the `myuser` was unable to create a local repository. This is because when you created the new user using the `useradd` command, it did not create the home directory for that user. Hence the `/home/myuser` directory was missing in the first place.

`-m` option in the `useradd` command will create the home directory if not present and `-s` option sets the home directory on the login shell.

Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182324/522304

Comment: -m should be enough and will create the correct home directory without the -d, since the default for the home directory will be /home/myuser.